# no matching function for call in rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

When using Rcpp,I create a function named rpois_rcpp and l try to call it below in genDataList function, an error occurs and said :
"no matching function for call to 'cpprbinom',
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'arma::vec' (aka 'Col') to 'Rcpp::NumericVector' (aka 'Vector<14>') for 3rd argument
arma::vec cpprbinom(int n, double size, NumericVector prob).

Can someone help me ,thanks!

Here is my code:

```
//create a random matrix X with covariance matrix sigma
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat mvrnormArma(const int n, arma::vec mu, const int p, const 
double rho) {

  arma::mat sigma(p, p, arma::fill::zeros);

  for (int i = 0; i < sigma.n_rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sigma.n_cols; ++j) {
      sigma(i,j) = pow(rho, abs((i + 1) - (j + 1)));
    }
  }

  int ncols = sigma.n_cols;
  arma::mat Y = arma::randn(n, ncols);


  return arma::repmat(mu, 1, n).t() + Y * arma::chol(sigma);
}

//create a vector sampled from poisson distribution with mean vector 
//lambda
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec rpois_rcpp( NumericVector &lambda) {
  int n= lambda.length();
  unsigned int lambda_i = 0;
  IntegerVector sim(n);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sim[i] = R::rpois(lambda[lambda_i]);
    // update lambda_i to match next realized value with correct mean
    lambda_i++;

  }
  return  as<arma::vec>(sim);
}

//create a vector sampled from binomial distribution with probability 
vector prob
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec cpprbinom(int n, double size, NumericVector prob) { 
  NumericVector v = no_init(n);
  std::transform( prob.begin(), prob.end(), v.begin(), [=](double p){ 
      return R::rbinom(size, p); }); 
  return as<arma::vec>(v);}




// [[Rcpp::export]]44
List genDataList(int n, arma::vec& mu, int p, double rho,
             arma::vec& beta, const double SNR, const std::string & 
  Test_case) {

  arma::mat U, V, data, normData, Projection;
  arma::vec s, y, means, noise;

  data = mvrnormArma(n, mu, p, rho);
  normData = arma::normalise(data,2,0);
  arma::svd_econ(U,s,V,normData,"right");
  Projection = V * trans(V);
  beta = Projection * beta;


  if(Test_case == "gaussian")
  {
    means=normData * beta;
    y = means + arma::randn(n) * sqrt(arma::var(means) / SNR);}
  else if (Test_case == "poisson")
  {
    means=exp(normData * beta);
    y = rpois_rcpp(means);}
  else
  {
    means=exp(normData * beta)/(1 + exp(normData * beta));
    y = cpprbinom(n,1,means);}




  List ret;
  ret["data"] = data;
  ret["normData"] = normData;
  ret["V"] = V;
  ret["beta"] = beta;
  ret["y"] = y;
  return ret;

  }
```

Comment: At StackOverflow the code must be text and be in the question.

Comment: As @drescherjm suggests, it would help us help you if you [edit] your question to copy and paste your code as text in your question itself (we can't very well copy and paste your code from an image to be able to check it out ourselves)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Have a look around at existing questions for tag `[rcpp]` -- yours is currently not in a form in which we can add much.  An [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot.

Comment: @duckmayr @ Dirk Eddelbuettel @ drescherjm Thanks so much l just fixed that

Comment: Hello Mohan, welcome to StackOverflow, just a question, how do you apply your function? Could you share a sample dataset and your function in R?

Comment: @Manu Hi Manu,I don't apply cpprbinom in R because it's only needed in genDataList function to generate y.However, l called it in R block to test :  pp <-rpois_rcpp(c(1:3)) and it works. But calling it within another c++ function doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for adding your code. When I tried to compile, I got the same error as you, but *also* an error for the line calling `rpois_rcpp()`

> invalid initialization of reference to type 'Rcpp::NumericVector&'

Pretty much everything seems to be in `arma`, except the R bindings and calls to the `R::` namespace, which takes doubles, ints, etc. It seems the easiest thing to do (to my mind), is just take `arma::vec` as arguments instead:

```cpp
arma::vec rpois_rcpp( arma::vec &lambda) {
    int n= lambda.n_elem;
```

and

```cpp
    arma::vec cpprbinom(int n, double size, arma::vec prob) {
```

You never utilize the fact that `lambda` and `prob` are `Rcpp::NumericVector`s specifically, you just use `double`s from them, so this seems the easiest route to me. After those changes, your code compiles fine on my machine. I don't have any test cases to make sure they run as you'd expect, but I imagine they will.

Comment: Thanks so much,It worked on my computer. I usually get confused about which one to use , numeric vector or arma::vec , this one really helps!